# How to passing multiple value using one id into modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have created button renderer in JQXgrid, when the button clicked, it passing data into controller, and controller send into model, then return with result from data from mysql.

This is my view code-part button renderer:

```
var button_renderer = function (row, columnfield, value, defaulthtml, columnproperties) {
            var kode_keramik = $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('getcelltext', row, "kode_keramik");
            button = '<a href="#modal_details" class="btn btn-xs btn-success view_details" id="'+ kode_keramik +'" >Proceed</a>';
            return button;
            };
```

This is my view code-part passing data to controller :

```
$(document).on('click', ".view_details", function() {

            //alert("aaa");
            var url = "<?php echo base_url().'getGlazeMM/ajax_get_item_list'?>";
            kode_keramik = this.id;

            $.post(url, {kode_keramik: kode_keramik} ,function(data) {
                $('.modal-body').empty();
                $('.modal-body').append(data);
                $('#modal_details').modal();
            });

        });
```

This is my controller :

```
public function ajax_get_item_list(){

      $data['post'] = $_POST;
      $kode_keramik = $_POST['kode_keramik'];
      //$buyer = $_POST['buyer'];

      $this->load->model('get_glaze');

      $data['item_list'] = $this->get_glaze->action_ajax_get_item_list( $data['post'] );

      if ($data['item_list']){

         echo "<table class='table table-bordered'>
                  <tr>
                     <th>Inspect Date</th>
                     <th>Item Code</th>
                     <th>Type</th>
                     <th>Hasil KW1</th>
                     <th>Total Inspek</th>
                     <th>Aktual Yield</th>
                     <th>Buyer</th>
                  </tr>";

         foreach ($data['item_list'] as $key => $value) {

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$value['inspect_date']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$value['item_code']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$value['sell_type']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$value['hasil_kw1']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$value['total_inspek']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$value['aktual_yield']." %</td>";
            echo "<td>".$kode_keramik."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

         }

         echo "</table>";

      } else {
         echo "Data tidak ditemukan";
      }

   }
```

The big question is how to passing multiple data from `view_details" id="'+ kode_keramik +'"` + ***SECOND VALUE*** on

```
var button_renderer = function (row, columnfield, value, defaulthtml, columnproperties) {
            var kode_keramik = $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('getcelltext', row, "kode_keramik");
            button = '<a href="#modal_details" class="btn btn-xs btn-success view_details" id="'+ kode_keramik +'" >Proceed</a>';
            return button;
            };
```

into :

```
var url = "<?php echo base_url().'getGlazeMM/ajax_get_item_list'?>";
            kode_keramik = this.id;
            ***SECOND VALUE;***

            $.post(url, {kode_keramik: kode_keramik, ***SECOND VALUE***} ,function(data) {
```

Until Controller :

```
public function ajax_get_item_list(){

      $data['post'] = $_POST;
      $kode_keramik = $_POST['kode_keramik'];
      $***SECOND VALUE*** = $_POST['***SECOND VALUE***'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format your data as one `JSON` object, and put it inside custom html attribute.

**Example**

Please be careful with **single quote** and ***double quotes escaping***.

```
var button_renderer = function (row, columnfield, value, defaulthtml, columnproperties) {
  var kode_keramik = $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('getcelltext', row, "kode_keramik");
  button = "<a href='#modal_details' class='btn btn-xs btn-success view_details' data-custom='{\"kode_keramik\": \"" + kode_keramik + "\", \"second\": \"value\"}'>Proceed</a>";
  return button;
};
```

Retrieving our object with `jQuery`

```
$(document).on('click', ".view_details", function() {
  //alert("aaa");
  var url = "<?php echo base_url().'getGlazeMM/ajax_get_item_list'?>";

  var obj = $(this).data('custom');   // get object using jQuery

  $.post(url, obj ,function(data) {
      $('.modal-body').empty();
      $('.modal-body').append(data);
      $('#modal_details').modal();
  });

});
```

It will parse the object **automatically**.